# Kony: Ant build error=exec-shell returned: 1

Tags: android, ant, cross-platform, temenos-quantum

While building "Hello World" project I have build and get build error as

```
Ant build error=exec-shell returned: 1
```

All Enviorment variable are set properly as follows.

**ANT_HOME : D:\Kony\Ant;**

**JAVA_HOME : D:\jdk1.7.0_75;**

**PATH:\Kony\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;D:\Kony\ImageMagick;C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;**

I just want to see results on emulator, correct me if any file location is wrong.

Comment: take a look [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and I'm getting frustrated looking for some correct answers

Answer (score 1):

I've found an interesting thread on the Kony Forums that might be the answer to your problem.  Give it a try

http://community.kony.com/developer/forum/ant-build-error-using-map

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll up in the error log, there might be more detailed info, e.g.:

```
[exec-shell] BUILD FAILED
[exec-shell] /Android-SDK/tools/ant/build.xml:716: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec-shell] /Android-SDK/tools/ant/build.xml:730: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
[exec-shell] 
[exec-shell] Total time: 1 second
[exec-shell]     [javac] /build/luaandroid/dist/src/com/konylabs/ffi/xxx.java:104: package xxx does not exist
```

If it is an error because Google Maps were included, modifying the "target=android-9" in \android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\project.properties to either "target=android-10" or "target=android-8" might help.

Answer (score -1):

ANDROID_HOME `D:\android-sdk-windows_new version`

ANT_HOME `C:\apache-ant-1.8.2`

JAVA_HOME `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`

Path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;D:\android-sdk-windows_new version\platform-tools;D:\android-sdk-windows_new version;D:\ImageMagick-6.4.0-Q16;C:\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.8.2\lib;D:\android-sdk-windows_new version\tools`

Note : Instead of apache ant , you can use kony ant also. Apache ant you can download.